# Merge commit from Master-branch to another branch, but not to merge two branches

Tags: git

1. I have git repository with one master branch.
2. I decided to develop new feature and I have created new branch 'new_branch'
3. I have created some commits in 'new_branch", but I am not finished new feature yet
4. I decided to fix some bug in master branch, so I switch to master branch, fix code and made commits.

Now, I want to have all fixes (all commits) from Master branch into 'new_branch'.  But I don't want merge two branches into one, because my new feature is not fully developed yet.  How can I do it ?

Comment: Merging doesn't eliminate a branch.  You can merge `master` into `new_branch` and still have two separate branches to work on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merge your master branch into your feature branch.

```
git merge master new_branch
```

Now, the fixes in master are applied to `new_branch`, and you can continue developing your new feature on `new_branch`.