# How to fetch updated code form master in earlier created branch in git

Tags: ios, git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using git for 1st time. I had created a branch on git, after creating branch I had not work on that branch, I did work in master. now I want that changes in my branch also so how can I pull these changes in my branch.

I am using source tree.

Comment: You need to checkout your branch and then merge merge master.

Comment: Actually I want to merge Master into branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge commit from Master-branch to another branch, but not to merge two branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682593/merge-commit-from-master-branch-to-another-branch-but-not-to-merge-two-branches)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-in-master-into-branch-in-git http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955980/git-merge-master-into-feature-branch

Comment: @random as I am not using  terminal, I am using source-tree.

Comment: You are also not using GitHub, or iPhone, or iOS

Comment: GitHub is not the same as Git

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58589/discussion-between-bhupesh-and-random).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SourceTree you can easily merge these changes into "your branch":

1. Make sure to checkout `master`, e.g. by double-clicking on it in the "BRANCHES" section on the left-hand side.
2. Select the commit of your branch and press the `Merge` button in the icon bar. You will be asked if you want to merge that branch into the current branch (which is `master`).

After doing so your branch should be on the same commit like `master`.